# PHP - imagettftext not working and GD installed

Tags: php, image, gd, imagettftext

It's being long hours that I'm still looking for answer to this problem..
All the solutions I find are around catching the font name but I am pretty sure this isn't my problem.

**It looks like GD is installed**

```
array(11) {
  ["GD Version"]=>
  string(27) "bundled (**2.0.34 compatible**)"
  ["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["T1Lib Support"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["WBMP Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XPM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["XBM Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Above you can see my GD support.
My PHP version is 5.3 and I'm running on Linux.

I have tried few different code examples from different websites and none works.
ImageString does work for me but I need to get **imagettftext** to work..

This is the last code I have tried now-

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 100) or die("Can't create image!");

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, 'arial.ttf', $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, 'arial.ttf', $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Result:** http://www.7679679.com/app/test-ansi.php

Comment: If you set header... just before imagepng, what errormsg do you get?

Comment: Does php give you any error/notice? What does `imagettftext` function return? It should returns array of points or false on error. try `$text_result = imagettftext(...); if($text_result===false){echo("ERROR");}else print_r($text_result);`. Another thing, when you are filling your newly created image, you left one pixel on height and filled only 29 pixels of 100 on width, is that on purpose?

Comment: how did you print that array???

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 21):

Had the same problem, with FreeType installed, solution was

```
 $font = "./Arial.ttf"; // <--- put ./ in front of filename
```

Comment: Worked for me! Lol! Can you please explain in detail why this works?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea of why this is so!

Comment: worked! - but really weird, would also like to know why this is happening?

Comment: I even had to add realpath('./Arial.ttf')

Comment: defined('ROOT_PATH') || define('ROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '')); $font_path = ROOT_PATH.'/fonts/arial-italic.ttf';

Answer (score 8):

Notice you don't have Free Type installed:

```
["FreeType Support"]=>
  bool(false)
```

**This function requires both the GD library and the » FreeType library.**

You will need to install Free Type library before you can use this function.

try installing these package:s **freetype, freetype-devel**

If you compiled PHP you can make sure you added enabled freetype during compile time:

```
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/ --with-freetype
```

Or if you using something such as YUM or APT-GET it should be really simple to install those libraries, and a quick search ob google with get you started.

Comment: Requirement for Freetype support is documented in PHP manual, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Answer (score 8):

Well i also got problem around

```
$font='arial.tff';
```

I think you should provide absolute path to the **$font** like

```
$font="c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
```

i assume you are a windows user.
and **remove**

```
header('Content-Type:image/png');
```

to get the real error

Comment: adding local path might not be a perfect solution maybe use getcwd() + file name.

Comment: @Damiani you are absolutely correct, but this path is for the font installed in OS, I will update the answer. Thanks for valuable suggestion

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem with this solution:

```
$fontfile= __DIR__.'/Fontname.ttf';
```

Answer (score -1):

Andrew is right, the [php manual for imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) states FreeType is required to use `imagettftext`, `imagettfbox`, and others. Most people the GD devel package will install FreeType automatically:

Fedora/Redhat:

```
yum install gd gd-devel php-gd
```

Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php5-gd libgd2-xpm libgd2-xpm-dev
```

This error was probably in your logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imageTTFText()
```